# How do I transform this dictionary in python?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I'm getting results from an external API as a dictionary in the format:

`{data:[{values:[{'end_time':'2013-10-03T07:00:00+0000', value:{'mobile':4, 'search':3}}, {'end_time':'2013-10-04T07:00:00+0000', value:{'source':2}}]}]}`

and I want to transform it into a dictionary with the format:

`{'2013-10-03T07:00:00+0000':{'mobile':4, 'search':3},'2013-10-04T07:00:00+0000':{'source':2}}`

When I try the following, I get the error `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression` for the line starting with `output_dict`:

```
def dict_cleaner(input_dict):
    for day in input_dict['data'][0]['values'][0]['end_time']:
        output_dict = dict(input_dict['data'][0]['values'][0]['end_time']=input_dict['data'][0]['values'][0]['value'])
    return output_dict
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: On the third line, inside the call to `dict`, you wrote `input_dict['data'][0]['values'][0]['end_time']=input_dict['data'][0]['values'][0]['value']`. What is that supposed to mean? I don't think Python likes that there is an equals sign in there.

Comment: I was trying to both create and update a dictionary using dict(key=value). Maybe the problem is if I'm looping through this dictionary, it chokes when it tries to add the second value, so perhaps I should be first doing output_dict = dict() and then output_dict.update = dict(key=value). But yeah, now that I look at it, you're totally right, I don't even need this for loop.

Comment: `update` is probably a good idea, although `output_dict.update = ...` doesn't make too much sense. `update` is a method, so you should call it using parentheses, not assign to it using equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kevin is right. If you're trying to create a dict why not just do

```
{input_dict['data'][0]['values'][0]['end_time']: input_dict['data'][0]['values'][0]['value']}
```

also, you can try comprehension instead of looping

```
output_dict = {d['end_time']: d['value'] for d in input_dict['data'][0]['values']}
```